# Compiling a kernel module using makefile in linux

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am new to kernel programming. I ahve written a hello world program but I am not able to complie it. I have serached and so made a make file under /usr/src and then doing sudo make command to run it. But its giving the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic-pae/build M=/usr/src modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/hello.c', needed by  `/usr/src   /hello.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

make file:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

hello.c (in ~Desktop/inet/)

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>   
int init_module(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

 /* 
 * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded. 
 */
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

In makefile I have taken care that every new line has a tab space only!

Please can some tell the problem!

Comment: Too bad formatting. Please format the code and output messages correctly.

Comment: Are you running `make` from `/usr/src`? And your source file lives in `$HOME/Desktop/inet`? The error is from make not knowing how to build a file that doesn't exist (`/usr/src/hello.c`) because that's not where your file is. I don't know the kernel build system enough to know what the right fix is here but that's the problem.

Comment: your Makefile should be `~Desktop/inet/` and not in `/usr/src`

Comment: if my memory is correct, you need to claim `init_module` as `__attribute__((constructor))` . similar to `cleanup_module` as `destructor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `Makefile` to where the module source `hello.c` is. That means in `~/Desktop/inet/`. Looks like you have put the `Makefile` in `/usr/src/`

```
$ sudo mv /usr/src/Makefile ~/Desktop/inet/
$ cd ~/Desktop/inet/
$ make
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `make` instead of `sudo make`